# c# : how to find highest average between multiple averages

Tags: c#

My code is below, the purpose is to get the number of students, as well as their name and 5 marks each and then display for each student:

- sum
- average
- number of marks over 50
  (all the above mentioned works)

***THIS IS THE PART THAT I CANT GET TO WORK:***
I have to display the name and mark of the student with the highest average. So it has to remember each person's average and find the highest, how do I do this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int gt50Count = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("How many students are there?");
        int students = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int y = 1; y <= students; y++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your mark");
                int mark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (mark > 100 || mark < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid mark,Enter your mark again");

                    int newmark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    mark = newmark;
                }

                total += mark;

                if (mark >= 50)
                {
                    gt50Count++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("sum = " + total);

            double average = (total / 5.0) * 1.00;
            Console.WriteLine("average = " + average);

            Console.WriteLine("Greater or equal to 50 count = " + gt50Count);
            Console.ReadLine();

            total = 0;
            gt50Count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before your for loops create a variable that stores the name of the highest average and the current high score. After calculating each average check if its higher than the current score. If it is change the name to the current student.

Comment: Use `TryParse`, not `Parse`.  Someone might enter a non-number, and then your program will crash.

Comment: Remember to consider all the possible cases. What will you do if someone enters zero students?  There is no highest mark then.

Comment: Remember to consider all the possible cases. What will you do if someone enters an invalid mark *twice in a row*?

Comment: Consider using a class that can hold a student name and marks, and then populate a list of these classes (one for each student) in your loop. After you're done collecting the information, you can get sums, averages, and find the highest marks.

Comment: @RufusL: The student is having some difficulty with loops; this might be their first day programming. Yes, your solution is the well-engineered one, but students need to walk before they run.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, of course you're right. I don't think I read the question carefully enough, and definitely didn't read between the lines.

Comment: What will you do if someone enters an invalid number of students?

Answer (score 2):

> So it has to remember each person's average and find the highest, how do I do this?

The general pattern goes like this: loop through the elements, fetching the current element.  Have we already got a highest element?  If no, then the current element is automatically the highest.  If yes, is the current element higher?  If yes, then it is the highest element so far.

```
bool gotHighest = false;
T highest = default(T);
some_looping_construct
{
  T current = code that gets the current T.
  if (gotHighest)
  {
    if (current > highest)
      highest = current
  }
  else 
  {
    highest = current;
    gotHighest = true;
  }
}
// Now if gotHighest is false, there was no highest element.
// If it is true, then highest is the highest element.
```

Can you apply this pattern to your program?

Comment: not exactly sure how to apply it?

Comment: Read his comments in your original question and concentrate on the logic. Try to visually walk though the program and what steps it needs to take to accomplish what you want it to do.